# Query Logic: Grouping tags by their count and another parameter

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the following scenario:

**Tables**

- 'posts'
      (omitted for brevity)
- 'tags'

  ```
  'id', 'name', 'kind' (kind = $table->enum('kind', array('male', 'female')))
  ```
- 'post_tag' (pivot table)

  ```
  'id', 'post_id', 'tag_id'
  ```

**Models**

- `Models\Post.php`

  ```
  public function tags()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Models\Tag');
  }
  ```
- `Models\Tag.php`

  ```
  public function posts()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Models\Post');
  }
  ```

**Controller**

```
$slug = 'hello-world';
$post = $this->posts->getFirstBy('slug', $slug);
$tags = $post->tags;
```

**Example Output of** `$tags`

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'rough' (length=5)
      'kind' => string 'male' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'cosy' (length=4)
      'kind' => string 'female' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'cosy' (length=4)
      'kind' => string 'female' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'cosy' (length=4)
      'kind' => string 'female' (length=6)
  4 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'sensual' (length=7)
      'kind' => string 'female' (length=6)
  5 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 4
      'name' => string 'hard' (length=4)
      'kind' => string 'male' (length=4)
  6 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'rough' (length=4)
      'kind' => string 'male' (length=4)
```

In my template I'd like to group the data like so:

**male**

```
- rough (2 occurances)
- hard (1 occurance)
```

**female**

```
- cosy (3 occurances)
- sensual (1 occurance)
```

Notice the order is highest number of occurances to lowest.
So, not only do I need to have access to the count of the tags, but I also need them grouped by the `kind` property (*male* and *female* in this example).

What kind of query do I need to perform to get the desired output? Unfortunately I'm not very good at creating MySQL statements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work (Not 100% sure because not tested but give it a try):

```
$u = Posts::with(array('tags' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('count(name) as total'))
          ->groupBy('kind')
          ->orderBy('total', 'desc');
}))->whereSlug('hello-world')->first();
```

*Please lemme know the result.*